# AutoResizeTextView changes size to minimum on using "\n" in string

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview

I'm using [AutoResizeTextView](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AutoFitTextView/blob/master/AutoFitTextViewLibrary/src/com/lb/auto_fit_textview/AutoResizeTextView.java) library .it is working fine on String like

```
String text="Some text goes here";
textview.setText(text);
```

But when i try to write

```
String text="Some text \n goes here";
textview.setText(text);
```

it takes the text to nextline but sets the size to minimum

Comment: In the second case, you don't have enought space.

Comment: no more than half of the screen remains empty

Comment: Its probably the height of the element is too small. Please provide your layout file.